# Can a RAID 10 array be transferred from a Windows box to a Synology (or other) enclosure?

Tags: raid, raid10

Currently I'm debating about whether I want to use a spare workstation running Windows 10 and turn that into the enclosure for a 4x6TB RAID 10 array since it has decent hardware specs or wait until there's room in the budget to purchase a dedicated NAS enclosure from Synology or some other vendor if what I want isn't possible as I would have to reformat/re-array for the enclosure. I know there is some difficulty with software <-> hardware driven array migrations according to this Q&A from '09:

[Moving a RAID array from one machine to another](https://serverfault.com/questions/61823/moving-a-raid-array-from-one-machine-to-another)

However given 7 years have passed and the rise of NAS storage for small business I was wondering if things have changed and if it's possible to have the RAID 10 initially set up in a spare workstation to use now and then migrate the RAID array and it's data w/o issue to a dedicated NAS enclosure from Synology et al when there's more money so that I can then free up the workstation again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a duplicate of the old question.  It's not clear exactly what you plan to do, but the first answer there seems to cover all the reasonable scenarios.

Unfortunately, what you seem to want to do (software RAID on the Win10 box and then hardware but you want to keep the same disks?) isn't "reasonable."  In that case, you'd be better off backing up the data, move the disks and make a new array, then restore the data.

Comment: It is a duplicate in a loose sense. I figured enough would have changed in the tech sphere in 7 years to warrant a reask rather than pinging an answered question. It would seem this is not the case and I will either have to decide to stick with Win10 software array/enclosures or pick a hardware RAID controller from Synology et al when there's the money for it and get a new controller from said brand every time the controller fizzes out...